# JOGL creating stack buffer overflow on windows

Tags: java, jogl

I am using JOGL in my application, and it is not the first time. In my module i have the following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
        <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In the parents `<dependencyManagement>` the version 2.3.1 is used for JOGL.

So far so good, I am now having the following simple class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GLProfile profile = GLProfile.getDefault();
    }
}
```

I have set `-Djava.library.path`to the correct windows-amd64 natives, and am getting the following error: `Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)`

According to error codes from windows that means stack buffer overflow. I have had a lot of issues with JOGL but this a first. Is there like some common use case where this happens?

Comment: Are you sure you set up properly the native? If you remove `windows-amd64` from the path, does it complain? Did you try a basic test without maven?

Comment: When I used the fat-jar approach from the Wiki it creates an executable jar that I can run without problems, but starting it from within IntelliJ it wont work. Setting natives or not setting them does not change anything, so I kind of assume that the error is somewhat unrelated to the natives.

Comment: Could you set a minimal sample on github?

Comment: JogAmp's Ardor3D Continuation uses JOGL with Maven, it works like a charm. Please have a look at JOGL user's guide, you don't have to set the library path if you use the automated native library loading which is enabled by default. I advise you to run your program on another machine, maybe there is a problem specific to a particular driver. Maybe there is another problem with IntelliJ as it should be able to run your fat JAR if it contains the correct native libraries in the expected layout (i.e /natives/<os.and.arch>/) and if GlueGen succeeds in extracting and loading them.